# ReadCString & WriteCString Missing

Tags: c#, .net, mono

Mono's BinaryWriter & BinaryReader in System.IO do not have methods for reading and writing CStrings.

Does this exist somewhere else in Mono?

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but what's a `CString`? Can you provide msdn link? I couldn't find anything about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Jester I should have checked there first, I figured it was a member but it most certainly wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a static method in a library I failed to import.
Remind me to check MSDN next time.